# Automatically download Google Sheet into a specific folder by script

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to automatize the following steps by google script.
Google Sheet -> File -> Download as -> Microsoft Excel 
I would like to save the file on my hard drive into a specific folder.

How can I automatize this task with google script?

```
function downloadXLSX() {
  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  var URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+ssID+'/export?format=xlsx';
  *******HERE SHOULD BE THE PART TO DOWNLOAD INTO THE SPECIFIC FOLDER******
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why the Excel tag?  I think I know Excel but there's no way I could answer this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function downloadXLSX() {
  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  var URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+ssID+'/export?format=xlsx';
  var blob;
  var response = "";
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });

  blob = response.getBlob().setName('document.xlsx');// Convert the response to a blob 

  DriveApp.createFile(blob); // Create a file with the blob and place it to Drive's root
}
```

You can't save on your hard disk from a script, but you can sending yourself by e-mail or save it throw your Drive account (and get it on your computer from the Drive application on PC/MAC).

You can use the [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) classe to get the response of your URL string. After, you using the [createFile(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFile(BlobSource)) method from DriveApp to create a file to the root of your Drive. See more about the [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) classe to move your file on the folder you want.

Comment: I did not know that I can not define a hard disk location. Thank you.

Comment: this was very useful thank you! I use to download reports with the current date so this helped a bunch